# Saving Input data into a file and loading it from the file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, console, loading, saving-data

I Have this question in programming, to create a student registration database (console application only). the part i do not get is this "Please note that all information regarding students should be stored in a file, when the application is closed and restarted, all previously entered data should be retrievable via the file." how do i creat that file..plz HELP!!!?

Comment: You Serialise your objects, and store them in a file!

Answer (score 0):

Simple Serialization can solve your problem. All you have to do is serialize your collection of students into a file using XML or Binary serialization. If you have a simple model class I would go with Binary serialization because it is straight forward to use. Since you didn't post any code I can't help you fix your own but here is information on how to serialize data to a file...

[Here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/serialize-list) is a good tutorial on how to serialize an deserialize a collection

Another alternative is to create a local database like SQL or SQLite and insert records into a database but that seems like overkill for what you are doing.

Comment: its an assignment so i cant post my code to be fixed but i need to understand how to really do it so i never have to ask again :-)..could you please write a simle code that would save the names of 5 students (using an array)

Comment: No sorry this isn't a place where people answer your homework for you. I provided you a link that has a very clear and concise example with code. Go read it.